# sql запрос в Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Всем привет, я создал две таблицы User и Account
Один user может иметь несколько аккаунтов

Это поле в сущности User

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Account>accounts;
```

Это поле в сущности

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Получатся в таблице аккаунты есть поле id_user
Как написать запрос в hibernate чтобы находило аккаунты юзера по имени и номеру телефона.

Пишу вот так, и hibernate не принимает

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select account from  account where user.name=:name AND user.number=:number");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from Account e where e.user.name=:name AND e.user.number=:number
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло, немного сбило с толку это "e.user.name". То есть мы переходим через таблицу аккаунтов в таблицу юзеров и в поле имя?

Comment: Мы должны указать к какой сущности относятся поля в запросе, в hql это делается через псевдоним. Документация рекомендует использовать в качестве них название класса сущности в нижнем регистре: `from Account as account`. Но это не критично.

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так это должно выглядеть:

```
List<Account> accounts = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil
    .getSessionFactory()
    .openSession()
    .createQuery("FROM Account WHERE user = '" + name + "' AND number = '" + number + "'")
    .list();
```